# JS files referencing confusing behavior

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

I have an ASP.Net site with some JS files references. In my master page header I have 3 files that are always referenced and a single function

```
    <script src="/EPS/Scripts/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/EPS/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/EPS/Scripts/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function checkJavaScriptValidity() {
            document.getElementById("jsDisabled").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById("jsEnabled").style.visibility = 'visible';            
        }

    </script>
```

Then in one of my aspx pages I have some more references (also added to the page header using `ContentPlaceHolders`)

```
    *JS1*<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5"></script>       
    <script src="/EPS/Scripts/savestate.js" type="text/javascript" >   </script>
    *JS2*<script src="/EPS/EPS_Controls/wcMapControl.js" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
```

**PROBLEM:**
I have a user control that uses the files I marked with **JS1** and **JS2** (these tags are not in the source code). When the control is loaded/used I get an error in the JS or it doesnt run. In the last couple of hours I tried a couple of things (order and place) and it didnt make a difference.

**Browsers**

*IE8:* In this current order I get *error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'undefined' is null or not an object"* in JS1

*FF v22.0* I dont get any error message (or atleast I couldnt find them) but I know that my JS didnt run

Now here is my **dilemma**, I used this **SAME** control and those **SAME** JS files in another test project and it works fine w/o any problems there!

**Question** Any clue/thoughts on why would this happen? What configurations in my project would affect/cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when it comes to javascript, everything depends on what the browser sees - there's nothing in your server code, your project configuration, or anything else in your app which would cause the issue with javascript.

With that in mind, just run View Source on your page. My guess is your script tags are getting put in after the control, so the control is attempting to do things that are not defined yet. Once you confirm this, figure out where the content placeholder with the scripts is, and move it accordingly - it probably is in the body now, and just needs to go into the head, or at least higher in the body.

Comment: My JS files are in the header while the control is in the body

Comment: While confirming the location of my JS files, I noticed a mistake in my control inner JS calls which would cause undefined, accepted as answer coz u pointed me in this direction

Answer (score 1):

To ensure correct loading of external scripts use ScriptManager in the master page and ScriptManagerProxy in content pages and user controls. For example, in master page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/EPS/Scripts/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/EPS/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/EPS/Scripts/menu.js" />
</Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

In a content page

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
<Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="https://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/EPS/Scripts/savestate.js" />
</Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use the SM to register the JS files instead of having them in my HTML?

Comment: @JafarKofahi Still use HTML (ASPX markup rather) but instead of referencing `<script src=` in pages headers use `<ScriptManager><Scripts>` `<ScriptManagerProxy><Scripts>` section. I will post the example

Comment: interesting +1 for the new info..thnx